# About matrix vector operations in Python

Tags: python, matrix, vector

I have a matrix of size nxm and a vector of size nx1. For example:

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[4,5,6]])
vector = np.array([[10],[20]])
```

I want to obtain `result = [[1+10, 2+10, 3+10],[4+20,5+20,6+20]] = [[11, 12, 13],[24,25,26]]`

I am a little bit confused about matrix operations in python. I couldn't find the correct one to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can just add them [numpy.add](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.add.html)

```py
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
vector = np.array([[10], [20]])

print(vector + matrix)
```

Output:

```
[[11 12 13]
 [24 25 26]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the output when added.

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3],[4,5,6]]
vector = [10,20]
result = []
x = 0
for elem in matrix:
    for nums in elem:
        result.append(nums+vector[x])
    x += 1
print(result)
```

Output

```
[11, 12, 13, 24, 25, 26]
```

Comment: thank you so much but I'm looking for something more simple, like a method of numpy if exist